# & после объявления функции в классе

Tags: c++, функции, c++11

```
class A
{
public:
    void f() &;
};
```

Что означает & после объявления функции?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Это означает, что функция может быть вызвана для `lvalue` объекта класса `A`.

Рассмотрите следующий пример

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void f() & { std::cout << "A::f() &" << std::endl; }
    void f() && { std::cout << "A::f() &&" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();
    A().f();
}
```

Вывод на консоль этой программы

```
A::f() &
A::f() &&
```

В классе `A` функция `f` перегружена для `lvale` объектов класса `A` и для `rvalue` объектов класса `A`.

В этой программе в предложении

```
    a.f();
```

вызывается функция `f` для `lvalue` объекта `a`.

В этом же предложении

```
    A().f();
```

вызывается функция `f` для `rvalue` объекта `A()`.

Другой пример.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void f() const & { std::cout << "A::f() const &" << std::endl; }
    void f() & { std::cout << "A::f() &" << std::endl; }
};

void h( const A &a )
{
    a.f();
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();

    h( a );
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
A::f() &
A::f() const &
```

В этом примере класс A объявляет две перегруженные функции с именем `f`: одна для константных `lvalue` объектов, а другая для неконстантных `lvalue` объектов.

В предложении

```
    a.f();
```

вызывается функция для неконстантных объектов, так как объект `a` не является константным.

Однако внутри функции `h`

```
    h( a );
```

вызывается перегруженная функция для константных объектов, так как параметр функции является константой ссылкой.

Еще один пример.

Данная программа не будет компилироваться

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void f() & { std::cout << "A::f() &" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A().f();
}
```

Потому что `rvalue`  не может быть привязана к неконстантной ссылке.

Однако если объявить функцию как имеющую дело с константной ссылкой, то программа будет компилироваться

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void f() const & { std::cout << "A::f() const &" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A().f();
}
```

Чтобы было более понятно, то можно представить эти функции следующим образом.

Каждая нестатическая функция-член класса имеет неявный параметр, который соответствует `this`

Поэтому данные две функции-члены класса

```
void f() const &
```

и

```
void f() &
```

концептуально выглядят как

```
void f( A * const & ) /*const &*/
```

и

```
void f( A * & ) /*&*/
```

Поэтому последнюю функцию нельзя вызывать для временных объектов типа `A *`, тогда как первую - можно, так как константная ссылка может привязыватья к временному объекту.

Вот пример, который упрощенно демонстрирует сказанное

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int * const  & ) { std::cout << "f( int * const & ) " << std::endl; }
void f( int * & ) { std::cout << "f( int * & )" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *pi = &i;

    f( pi );
    f( &i );
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
f( int * & )
f( int * const & )
```

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Возможно, что для временных объектов вы хотите иметь одно поведение, а для невременных объектов - другое.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Это какая-то очень новая конструкция? Не встречал её раньше.

Comment: @VladD Я тоже раньше не встречал, пока не задали этот вопрос.:) Впервые в жизни написал эти демонстрационные программы.:)

Comment: @VladD, 11 стандарт. Просто настолько редко используется, что всплывает только в «академических» вопросах. Можно почитать про неё по ключевым словам «rvalue this»

Comment: @Vlad , А как это расшифровывается: "int * const  &" ? привык проводить линию через * - левая часть к типу содержимого, правая к самому указателю, но тут еще &. Возможно & в выражении имеет больший приоритет чем *, через & надо проводить прямую. Тогда int * const  | p = ссылка на константный указатель, который содержит тип int? Если так int | const & p, бред - константная ссылка, они и так константные.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Да, это ссылка на константный объект или, как иногда говорится даже в самом стандарте, константная ссылка на объект. Строго говоря сами ссылки не могут быть константными. Они могут быть ссылками на константные объекты или неконстантные объекты. В данном примере это ссылка на константный указатель или константная ссылка на указатель.

Comment: f( int * const & ) ссылка на константный указатель, но тип который хранит указатель не константный, может быть нужно исправить в ответе на f( const int * & ) ?  У константного объекта this = const T*

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Имеется в виду ссылка на this. this - указатель. Константная ссылка, или точнее ссылка на константный this это означает то, что я написал.

Comment: rvalue сам указатель, а не тип на который он указывает.  f( &i ) - тут создается временный указатель? Не могу связать ваш пример с идеей неявного аргумента функции класса :(

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Да, в последнем примере rvalue  относится к указателю.

Comment: Тогда может быть void f() const & != void f( A * const & )? Или r/l value статус указателя зависит от статуса типа на который он ссылается? (скорей всего нет или ... , явно что то не так :) Ведь перегрузка должна зависеть именно от статуса(r/l) объекта, а не указателя на него.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Я в этом примере вместо самих объектов для наглядности использовал указатель на объект, чтобы показать различие между rvalue и lvalue.