# Амперсанды в сигнатуре функции-члена

Tags: c++, функции, классы, методы

Скажите как называются амперсанды в сигнатуре функции-члена и какую роль они выполняют. Вот пример:

```
class some_class
{
  void foo() & ; 
  void foo() && ;
  void foo() const & ;
  void foo() const && ;
};
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462775/398552

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Они называются *reference qualifiers*.

`&` означает, что этот метод можно вызывать только на lvalue, а `&&`, соответственно - только на rvalue.

В качестве исключения, `const &` методы можно вызывать и на rvalue.

---

Некоторые навешивают `&` на `operator=`, чтобы `some_class{} = ...` не компилировалось.

Еще, их можно использовать для хитрых оптимизаций вроде:

```
class Vector
{
    std::vector<int> vec;

    const std::vector<int> &GetValue() const & {return vec;}
    std::vector<int> &&GetValue() && {return std::move(vec);}
};
```

Comment: Уточнение.. Их так же называют "Ссылочные квалификаторы", либо "Ref-qualified member functions", либо "Ref-qualifiers for *this". Вот достаточно подробный разбор данного понятия на https://habr.com/ru/post/216783/

Comment: imho небольшой рассказ о том, что такое lvalue и rvalue был бы тут уместен, думаю далеко не все читатели ответа знают что это такое